# What does "Failed parsing 'srcset' attribute value since its 'w' descriptor is invalid." mean?

Tags: html, wordpress

I get Chrome errors on my website that say:

> Failed parsing 'srcset' attribute value since its 'w' descriptor is
>   invalid.
> Dropped srcset candidate
>   http://i2.wp.com/domain.net/wp-content/.../image.jpg?resize=425%2C200

Any idea what this means?

I am using WordPress as my website platform. I also use its Photon feature (within its Jetpack framework). My suspicion is that it has to do with this feature. Are image dimensions getting specified incorrectly or something?

What are 'w' descriptors?

---

**UPDATE**:
Here is the HTML:

```
<img src="http://i1.wp.com/gaithersburgpsychologist.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/lightbulb.jpg?resize=425%2C200"
   srcset="http://i1.wp.com/gaithersburgpsychologist.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/lightbulb.jpg?resize=425%2C200 w, http://i1.wp.com/gaithersburgpsychologist.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/lightbulb.jpg?resize=450%2C320 w"
   sizes="(min-width: 768px) 720px, (min-width: 992px) 700px, (min-width: 1200px) 850px, calc(100vw-20px)"
   alt="Change your thoughts and you change your world.">
```

Comment: It'll help to actually see the HTML source that Chrome is referring to (you may also get more information from [the W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/)).

Comment: Yeah, that might help. Added it.

Comment: The descriptor describes the physical width of the image candidate. It is a number followed by `w`. In your case the number is missing.

Comment: @alexanderfarkas Is there a spec you can point me to that describes this in more detail? This is not an aspect of HTML that I am familiar with.

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#introduction-3

Answer (score 40):

I had a similar error:

> failed parsing srcset attribute value since it has an unknown descriptor

and the problem was caused by a **space** in the image path URL.

Comment: yeah! For directories with spaces PHP can `echo str_replace(' ', '%20',$url);`

Comment: in my case there is a space in image url and have two dots before extension like (image..jpg)

Comment: It worked for me, after removing the spaces from URL the warning stops.

Answer (score 17):

**tldr; Your html is invalid and you are missing the actual width number.**

This is a valid img tag with srcset:

```
<img src="phone.jpg" srcset="phone-small.jpg 256w, phone-big.jpg 512w" />
```

It says that if your browser understands `srcset` it should use the small image when the width is approx 256 px wide, and the bigger image when it is 512 px wide.

In your image tag you have nothing in front of the `w`:

`srcset="http://...resize=425%2C200 w, ...`

Notice there is nothing specifying the width? That's the problem. Change it to something like `600w` to use the pic for screen widths of 600 pixels, etc.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I simply forgot to put a comma between the images

Comment: can you share code example to help make more sense of what you mean

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was generating my srcset using a webpack loader called [srcset-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/srcset-loader) who was outputing a JSON object instead of a proper string.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, as with all cases above the image URL was corrupt:

Example:

```
https://aaaa.aaaa.com/?somequery
```

Replacing /? with ? helped.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I was programatically creating the srcset sizes, and had a value like 347.99999w. Solved with a Math.floor().

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by removing the space from the url file name

Comment: there's no space in these urls. if there was, it should be urlencoded.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by amending 1X, 2X to 1x, 2x